# Removing specific words from a string input

Tags: c++, string, c++14

In the required code , I have to input a string and output that string after removing all occurences of a given word in that string.
Example: Say I wish to remove `WUB` from the string.

Input1: `WUBWUBABCWUB`

Output1:`ABC`

Input2:`WUBWEWUBAREWUBWUBTHEWUBCHAMPIONSWUBMYWUBFRIENDWUB`

Output2:`WE ARE THE CHAMPIONS MY FRIEND`

Here is my code:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string in;
    cin>>in;                           //input
    int n=in.length();

    int pos =in.find("WUB");
    for(;pos!=-1;){
            pos =in.find("WUB");
        if(pos!=-1){                //manipulating string by erasing and inserting spaces between words
            in.insert(pos+3," ");
            in.erase(pos,pos+3);
            }
    }
            if(in[0]==' ')
                in.erase(in.begin());
            if(in[n-1]==' ')                      //removing extra spaces
                in.erase(in.end());
    cout<<in;
}
```

It works for input 1, but for input 2 gives wrong output. Output2:`WEETHEONSND`

What is wrong here?

Comment: try using the debugger ..you are probably messing up with string length and index

Comment: 1) Don't `#include <bits/stdc++.h>` 2) Properly format your code, if not for yourself then for us. 3) As soon as `in` contains one "WUB", `in[n-1]` will read outside the string.

Comment: You can write the `pos = ...` at the end of the loop instead of the begin and remove `if(pos!=-1)`, by the way. Plus, `for(;pos!=-1;){` is just a strange way to write `while(pos!=-1)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The overload of `string::erase` you use is

```
basic_string& erase( size_type index = 0, size_type count = npos );
```

You are passing `pos+3` as count, instead of just 3.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of two sequential calls of the function insert and erase you could use only one call of the function replace.

Moreover this call of member function earse

```
in.erase(pos,pos+3);
```

The second argument shall specify the number of characters that need to be erased.

Also it seems you need to remove all leading and trailing blanks instead of only one blank from the both sides.

```
        if(in[0]==' ')
            in.erase(in.begin());
        if(in[n-1]==' ')                      //removing extra spaces
            in.erase(in.end());
```

The program can look the following way

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <limits>

int main() 
{
    while ( true )
    {
        std::cout << "Enter the source string (Enter - exit): ";

        std::string s;

        if ( not std::getline( std::cin, s ) or s.empty() ) break;

        std::cout << "Enter the substring to remove: ";

        std::string t;

        std::cin >> t;
        std::cin.ignore( std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n' );

        if ( not t.empty() )
        {
            for ( auto pos = s.find( t ); 
                  pos != std::string::npos;
                  pos = s.find( t, pos ) )
            {
                s.replace( pos, t.size(), 1, ' ' );
                ++pos;
            }                 
        }

        s.erase( 0, s.find_first_not_of( " \t " ) );
        auto pos = s.find_last_not_of( " \t " ); 
        if ( pos != std::string::npos ) s.erase( ++pos );

        std::cout << "The source string: \"" << s << "\"\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Its output might look like

```
Enter the source string (Enter - exit): WUBWUBABCWUB
Enter the substring to remove: WUB
The source string: "ABC"
Enter the source string (Enter - exit): WUBWEWUBAREWUBWUBTHEWUBCHAMPIONSWUBMYWUBFRIENDWUB
Enter the substring to remove: WUB
The source string: "WE ARE  THE CHAMPIONS MY FRIEND"
Enter the source string (Enter - exit):
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create more efficient and neat code by using **Regex** to find the unwanted words, and then replace them with a space. Of course you will then have to use unique() to remove the double spaces.

**Code**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <regex>

bool BothAreSpaces(char lhs, char rhs)
{
    return (lhs == rhs) && (lhs == ' ');
}

int main()
{
    string s("WUBWEWUBAREWUBWUBTHEWUBCHAMPIONSWUBMYWUBFRIENDWUB"); //Input string
    regex e("(WUB)");   // Regex syntax to filtr unwanted string
    string result; //Filtered string


    regex_replace(std::back_inserter(result), s.begin(), s.end(), e, " "); //Replace unwanted word with space
    string::iterator new_end = unique(result.begin(), result.end(), BothAreSpaces); //Find double spaces
    result.erase(new_end, result.end()); //Remove double spaces
    cout << result << endl;
}
```

**Output**

```
WE ARE THE CHAMPIONS MY FRIEND
```

Comment: Why are you not simply writing ````s=std::regex_replace(s,std::regex("WUB","")````?

Comment: I followed the regex documentation on cppreference, but yours works as well :)